# Clicking on a asp.net button, how to scroll down the page when there is an error on the form

Tags: asp.net, validation, button

My page scrolls down a bit, so the problem is when the ASP.NET validation kicks in (its a server side validation that sets a table row to visible if there was a failed validation for a given input box).

**The problem is, when there is an error, the page scrolls back to the top.**

How can I force the page to the bottom?

I can use `<a name="asdf"></name>` but the page doesn't refresh normally since its a asp.net image button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your error is near the button that performs the postback then you can set `MaintainScrollPosition` in the Page Declaration which will take you back to where you were after the postback.

Answer (score 1):

you can set it to scroll to the last control on the page:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("MyScrollingStuff", "<script language='javascript'>document.getElementById('" & myControl.ClientID & "').scrollIntoView();</script>")
```

or cheat:

```
<script>self.scrollTo(0, 2000000000);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the JavaScript window.scrollTo(x,y) method

```
function myScrollFunction(){
    window.scroll(400,400);
}
```

Add a clients side startupscript to call this function with appropriate values when your serverside validation fails.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Some people have javascripts turned off in their browsers but I don't know how they use much of the internet if they do.